# How to end up with a new Postgresql column value if there is a mismatch

Tags: postgresql

```
INSERT INTO main_parse_user ("user_id","group_id", "username","bio", "first_name")
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ON CONFLICT (user_id) DO UPDATE SET (group_id,username,bio,first_name) =
(EXCLUDED.group_id,EXCLUDED.username,
coalesce(main_parse_user.bio, EXCLUDED.bio),EXCLUDED.first_name)
```

Here is the code I have now, in case of a conflict, it updates everything except bio (if it is empty, it updates)

There was a new need to check with the old one when a new base arrives and, if the values ​​differ, to supplement, and if the values ​​do not differ, just leave it as it is

EXAMPLE

```
OLD
bio id
1 qwerty

NEW
bio id
1 qwerty1

AFTER
bio id
1 qwerty | 1
```

And if both bios in the old and new tables are the same, then do not touch

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is precisely does the `coalesce()` function does. Since the new requirement is to *to supplement* (I assume that means *add to the existing value*) you can replace, `coalesce(...)` with

```
case when main_parse_user.bio is distinct from EXCLUDED.bio
      and EXCLUDED.bio is not null 
     then concat(trim(main_parse_user.bio), ' ', trim(EXCLUDED.bio)) 
     else main_parse_user.bio
end
```

Comment: is it possible to make it so that when the value is```qwerty``` and if the new value is ```qwerty NEW```, he takes only ```NEW``` and removes the rest and so that it remains in the base ```qwerty NEW```